# C# - How to use specialised (derived) component on Windows Form

Tags: c#, charts, subclass

I've been working on a C# Windows Form Application that uses a graph. Up until now I have used C#'s generic `Chart` component and written various functions to implement the custom behaviour I have needed.

It has got to the point where there are more of these than I anticipated and I think the best option may be to make a subclass of `Chart` with the appropriate attributes and methods that I want. Something like this:

```
public class CustomVisual : Chart {
    //some custom attributes

    //some custom methods
}
```

What is important here is that I don't want the chart to look any different, just have some different behaviour.

With this being the case, what do I need to do to be able to add my `CustomVisual` to the form and have it look like any ordinary chart? Is this default behaviour, or do I have to design it somehow?

Comment: It depends how you are adding the charts to the form: if you are setting them in code, then you won't need to do anything, but if you add them from the Toolbox, then you would need to explicitly add the subclass to it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that!

Comment: If you want to get a visual reperesentation of your add-ons you need to make sure they work with the designer. Until you get that right you can 'comment' them out, ie make them conditional using an `if ( DesignMode )`. This may be necessary when your e.g. paint events only work when the chart has been initialzed..